# How to use DEFINE vars inside functions

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have a pure PHP script - no frameworks, no OOP - like this:

```
<?php

define('VAR1', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('VAR2', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('VAR3', 'xxxxxxxxxx');

function myFunction()
{

    // I need to access VAR1, VAR2, VAR3 here

}

$output = myFunction();
```

How do I access `VAR1`,`VAR2` and `VAR3` inside `myFunction()`? By declaring them as `GLOBAL` inside the function?

Comment: consider a PHP constant as a string that is just replaced with its value during runtime. Therefore you may use it whereever you want, no matter inside or outside of the function

Comment: Did you even tried to access them once ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of a constant is already global, so just use them as they are:

```
define('VAR1', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('VAR2', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('VAR3', 'xxxxxxxxxx');

function myFunction()
{
    echo VAR1;
    // I need to access VAR1, VAR2, VAR3 here

}

$output = myFunction();
```

Comment: (Not to be confused with *global variable scope* obviously...)

Answer (score 1):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php "*the scope of a constant is global. You can access constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope.*"

So, it's really easy:

```
<?php

define('VAR1', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('VAR2', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('VAR3', 'xxxxxxxxxx');

function myFunction()
{
  echo VAR1;
  echo VAR2;
  echo VAR3;
}

$output = myFunction();
```